# How do I remove the Facebook login prompt when displaying images pulled with graph api on a page?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-sdk-4.0

I recently started playing around with Facebook graph API and wanted to integrate images pulled from my Facebook page to display on my website. I have the images displaying properly but my problem is whenever anyone tries to view the page they are asked to log into Facebook first. Is there any way to display the images without prompting the user to log into Facebook?

Here is what I am using to make the session:

```
$app_id = 'id';
$app_secret = 'secret';
$redirect = 'my webpage';
// init app with app id and secret
FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication($app_id,$app_secret);
// login helper with redirect_uri
$helper = new FacebookRedirectLoginHelper($redirect);
try {
  $session = $helper->getSessionFromRedirect();
} catch( FacebookRequestException $ex ) {
  // When Facebook returns an error
} catch( Exception $ex ) {
  // When validation fails or other local issues
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If you are asking about getting photos from an actual Facebook Page (not user profile), then get a long-lived page access token and use that for your API requests. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens

Answer (score 0):

**Step one:** familiarize yourself with the API. Read the docs, and play around with the [Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/)

**Step two:** the code you provided has nothing to do with what you are trying to achieve (displaying page photos). That code is basically the getting started code used in the docs. If you need help, post the relevant code.

**Step three:** as mentioned by @CBroe, authenticating the *visitor* is not needed to display photos from a page. What you might want to explore:

- The page admin authenticating your app with the right permissions (maybe `manage_pages`)
- with the [*user* access token](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens) you just got, you extend it to long-lived one
- then you query the API to get a [*page* access token](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens#pagetokens) that won't expire
- you store this access token and query the API to get the relevant data **and** store it (`GET /{PAGE-ID}/photos` or `GET /{PAGE-ID}/albums` ... etc)
- you show the *stored* data to your visitors

**Notes:**

- Do *not* make these calls on client-side ... i.e. reveal your page access token, since you can do this in the backend.
- Use the [realtime updates](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/real-time-updates/v2.3) to get notified when you should query the API and get new photos ***instead*** of periodically querying the API to pull new photos, ***or even worst***, querying the API on each user visit.